Graphviz - Can you add a Summary Curly Braces to Multiple Nodes
Can I add a summary curly bracket (or similar kind of edge) to demonstrate a summary of the nodes above in Graphviz?
The picture below clearly shows what I am looking for.
(Note: I understand that I can rewrite the dot file to get what I am looking without using summary curly braces, but the example is simplified to ask a question, I have more complex graph relationship that needs the summary braces).
Thank you.


Please provide work-to-date.  As a reminder, you are supposed to "show your work", no matter how unsatisfactory.  Short answer: no.  Longer answer: maybe.  Let me ponder.

Without any fiddling, dot can get kind-of, fairly close:
digraph B {

splines=true
node[shape=box3d]

G->{a b}
a->{a1 a2 a3}
b->{b1 b2 b3}

a1:sw -> d1:n
a3:se -> d1:n

d1 -> e1

b1:sw -> d2:n
b3:se -> d2:n
d2-> e2

}

Giving:

Otherwise, it would require some post-processing.
Good enough?
Here is a gvpr (https://www.graphviz.org/pdf/gvpr.1.pdf) (comes w/ Graphviz) script that comes even closer.  Add brace=true to the appropriate edges above, then run the commands dot myFile.gv |gvpr -cf makeBraces.gvpr |neato -n2 -T...
/*********************************************************************
  makeBraces.gvpr
  change edges into a shape that resembles braces (using straight line segments)
  not industriaal-strength.
  only works on dot output && rankdir==TB  (default)

  usage
  - add "brace=true" attribute to each edge you want to redraw
  - command pipeline:
    dot myFile.gv | gvpr -cf makeBraces.gvpr | neato -n2 -T...

********************************************************************/
BEG_G{
  if (hasAttr($, "rankdir") && $.rankdir!="LR|RL") {
    printf(2,"Error, program does not work if rankdir=LR or RL\n");
    exit(2);
  }
}
E{
  int     cnt;
  float   dx, dy, x2, x3, y2, f;
  string  tok[int], aHead, tmpStr;

  if (hasAttr($, "brace") && $.brace!="") {
    cnt=tokens($.pos, tok);
    if (cnt!=5) {
      printf(2,"Error, expecting exactly 5 points in %s pos value.  Found %d\n", $.name, cnt);
      exit (1);
    }
    $.oldpos=$.pos;
    // create new edges
    dx=(float)xOf(tok[4])-(float)xOf(tok[1]);
    dy=(float)yOf(tok[4])-(float)yOf(tok[1]);
    print("//  dx: ", dx,"   dy: ", dy);
    aHead=substr(tok[0],2);
    y2=(float)yOf(tok[1]) + (dy/2);

    if (dx>0) {
      x2=(float)xOf(tok[1]) - (dy/2);
      x3=(float)xOf(aHead) + (dy/2);
    } else {
      x2=(float)xOf(tok[1]) + (dy/2);
      x3=(float)xOf(aHead) - (dy/2);
    }
    // build new pos string
    tmpStr=tok[0] + " ";  // arrowhead
    // 1st point == tok[1]
    tmpStr=tmpStr + tok[1] + " ";
    // 2 more with same X as tok[1], decreasing Y
    for (f=1; f<=2; f++) {
      tmpStr=tmpStr + xOf(tok[1])  +"," + (string)((float)yOf(tok[1]) + ((dy/2) * (f/2))) + " ";
    }
    // 4th point -- note use of dy
    //tmpStr=tmpStr + (string)((float)xOf(tok[1]) - (dy/(2.)))   +","+ (string)y2 + " ";
    tmpStr=tmpStr + (string)x2  +","+ (string)y2 + " ";
    // 2 more (horizontal section)  with increasing X and same Y
    for (f=1; f<=2; f++) {
      tmpStr=tmpStr + (string)((float)xOf(tok[1]) + ((dx)*f/4)) + "," + (string)y2 + " ";
    }
    // 3rd point -- note dy
    tmpStr=tmpStr + (string)x3 + "," + (string)y2 + " ";
    // 3 more (down to arrowhead section)
    for (f=1; f<=3; f++) {
      tmpStr=tmpStr + xOf(aHead)  +","+ (string)(y2 + (dy/2.)*f/3) + " ";
    }
    $.pos=tmpStr;
  }
}

Giving:


thank you so much for the detailed answer. I like the second approach. that can get a pretty close to the result I am looking for.
